# What is the meaning of scouring in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Just found my mom *scouring* Stackexchange.Was SO confused. so I double checked,only to find that she was on "Hinduism" Stackexchange.

The above is a tweet by a netizen. The dictionary meanings for scouring are
1.to remove dirt, grease.
2.to clear or dig out (a channel, drain, etc.) as by the force of water, by removing debris, etc.,

But I didn't quite understand the context of the meaning used in the tweet. Can anyone explain?

<sup>For those who are interested, are welcome to join [Hinduism.stackexchange.com](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [to scour (*verb*)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scour)
>
> is to go through or range over in or as if in a search

Apparently, Mom was searching through stackexchange.com, not trying to clean it.